# How to target elements inside <script setup> of Vue 3 component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

How can I target the element with `test` class inside this vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="test" class="test">

  </div>
</template>


<script setup>

console.log(document.querySelector('.test'))
</script>
```

This component is imported into another component. The console outputs `null`.

Comment: the component is likely not rendered before that script is run - you'll want to use `import { onMounted } from 'vue'; onMounted(() => { console.log(document.querySelector('.test')) }`

Comment: That was it! Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the component is not rendered before that script is run

You want to wait until it is mounted

```
<template>
  <div id="test" class="test">

  </div>
</template>


<script setup>

import { onMounted } from 'vue'; 
onMounted(() => { 
    console.log(document.querySelector('.test')) 
});
</script>
```

In general, there's hardly ever any need to use DOM methods like that in vue though - I won't say never, because I know as soon as I say that, someone will come up with a **valid** reason to

I never have though

Answer (score 6):

The best practice is to use ref instead of DOM manipulations methods, and also use `onMounted` hook to check the element as mentioned in the following example:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref,onMounted } from 'vue'

const input =ref()
onMounted(()=>{

  input.value.focus()
})
</script>

<template>

  <input  ref="input">
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onMounted` for target the element inside vue component:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.test'));
})
</script>
```

but I recommend use `ref` instead of DOM manipulations method:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const el = ref()

onMounted(() => {
  el.value // <div>
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="el"></div>
</template>
```

docs: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted